# PHP Date Not Functioning As Expected

Tags: php

I have tried for hours to figure this out and it's beaten me. Why does $currentDay return a number representing the day of the week? Can I not assign a variable to the date?

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$currentDay = date('l'); // dayname
$currentTime = date("H");
$preOpen = "We're Open";
$preClosed = "We're Closed";
if ($currentDay = "Thursday" && $currentTime >= "22") {
  echo $preClosed."<br>";
} elseif ($currentDay = "Friday") {
  echo $preClosed."<br>";
} elseif ($currentDay = "Saturday" && $currentTime >= "22") {
  echo $preClosed."<br>";
} else {echo $preOpen."<br>";
}
echo date('l')."<br>";
echo $currentDay
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `if` statements, you need to use `==` to check equality instead of `=`.

With your current code, when you write `($currentDay = "Thursday" && $currentTime >= "22")`, PHP is actually evaluating the value `"Thursday" && $currentTime >= "22"` as a boolean (which returns `1` right now, after 10 PM in New York) and *assigning* it to `$currentDay`.

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/ChocolateWindingAtom#main.php)